# pod install error [!] Unable to add a source with url named "master-1"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using xcode 6.2 on OS X 10.9.5

I have installed ruby v2.6.3p62 and pod v1.6.1,
and already clone the .cocoapods/repos/master,

after that run command in my project directory:

```
pod init
```

to create Podfile and add "pod 'Alamofire'" into the file to add dependencies

But, when I run command:

```
pod install
```

I've got this message:

```
Analyzing dependencies
env: illegal option -- u
usage: env [-i] [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
Setting up CocoaPods master repo

[i] Unable to add a source with url 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'named 'master-1.
You can try adding it manually in '/Users/myUser/.cocoapods/repos'or via 'pod repo add'.
```

I've tried to remove and reclone the .cocoapods/repos/master,

change the Command Line Tools in Xcode into Xcode 6.2 or set empty,

but it didn't solve the problem.

**Update**

here it is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynimic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
  pod 'Alamofire'

end
```

Comment: you have to update your pod.

Comment: show us your `Podfile`

Comment: hi @sn86 , what do you mean by update the pod? do you mean use 'pod update' ? unfortunately the issue still same with 'pod update'

Comment: @MatthewK Please check my answer.

Comment: hi @ChanakaCaldera , I have edited my question with the Podfile

Comment: @MatthewK are you sure about the internet connection. and please check https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293 and https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6269

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to follow these instruction mentioned?

1- First Step

> `$ cd /Users/username/.cocoapods/repos`

2- remove folder master if it exists

> `rm -rf master`

3- clone Cocoapods/Specs

> `$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

4- then pod setup

> `pod setup`

That's it

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to install `POD`:-**

- pod init (Create a new Podfile only if you don't have already, otherwise go to next step)
- open Podfile
- add `pod 'Alamofire'`
- pod install

Comment: yes I've did these steps but problem when run command 'pod install'

Comment: Can you show your Terminal Screenshot (of the Commands that you have run)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow the instructions mentioned?

Go in your terminal and:

```
cd /Users/myUser/.cocoapods/repos
```

followed by:

```
pod repo add https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master-1
```

Comment: hi @Durdu , when I tried the command, the message is "fatal: repository 'master-1' does not exist

Comment: I think you can do the following and it will resolve your problem, in a terminal: 
<<<cd ~/.cocoapods/repos>>> and then <<<git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master>>>

Comment: yes I have did it, and it run smoothly, but my question is when I tried to run command `pod install` in the project's directory to install project's dependencies it shows the error message

Answer (score 0):

Try below command.

`pod update YourPodName`

Here **YourPodName** stands with your podname.

Example :- `pod update Alamofire`

Comment: when I do that the message is '[i] The Alamofire Pod is not installed and cannot be updated'

Comment: Then at first you have to install the same pod. I think when you install the pod you will be get latest version. So, no need to update it.